# Synonym for "a tuple of" time and place

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there an elegant one-word english term for datums made of a combination of (meeting) time (span or point) and place?

Naturally you could say "time and place of ...", but when you speak of a meeting, you normally want to refer to them both at a time.

Comment: There is no way to refer to time and place as only a single thing. Why would there be?

Comment: @Lambie: Because it's a useful thing that people sometimes want to refer to? "Send me the <timeandplace> of the meeting, and I'll be there!"

Comment: *Details* or *arrangements* - in the real world you don't just want coordinates and time, but to know who's running the meeting and what the topic is.

Comment: @psmears Yes, the time and place of the meeting. There is no single word for that. I repeat: How could there be? So silly as to be stupid.

Comment: @Lambie: There are all sorts of words that refer to a combination of things that people commonly want to refer to together. There may not be one for precisely this example, but it's not *stupid* to imagine that there *might* be.

Comment: @psmears Yes, combinations of **things** but not **time and place**.

Comment: @Lambie: There's no _a priori_ reason why the combination of those particular things - needed for a meeting or other rendezvous - shouldn't have its own word. For instance, "setting" is [defined](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/setting) as "the time and the place in which the action of a book, film, play, etc. happens" - now that may be too specific for the OP's purposes, but it definitely refers to the combination of time and place, so it's hardly that far-fetched a concept :)

Comment: @psmears Who said anything about *a priori*? I mean in practical terms. "setting" is a literary term.

Comment: @Lambie: Why is it stupid in practical terms? It arises quite often, in a work setting, that it's agreed (via email, instant messaging or some other medium) that a meeting is required about a particular topic, with particular attendees. All that's needed is to arrange a suitable time and location for everyone involved to actually meet. "I'll leave it to you sort out the <timeandplace>" is not an unreasonable statement to want to make. Just because there may not be a suitable single word for <timeandplace> doesn't make it _stupid_ to wonder whether one might exist.

Answer (score 2):

Well apart from bikeshedding your variable names this isn't such a bad question actually.

In physics space and time are considered to be aspects of the same thing, called ***[spacetime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime)***.

One term I've seen used to describe something located in spacetime is ***event***, but this term already has enough meanings (especially in computing). Here are some places the Wikipedia article uses this term:

> In cosmology, the concept of spacetime combines space and time to a single abstract universe. Mathematically it is a manifold consisting of "events" which are described by some type of coordinate system. Typically three spatial dimensions (length, width, height), and one temporal dimension (time) are required.
>
> For example, on the globe the latitude and longitude are two independent coordinates which together uniquely determine a location. In spacetime, a coordinate grid that spans the 3+1 dimensions locates events (rather than just points in space), i.e., time is added as another dimension to the coordinate grid.
>
> Spacetimes are the arenas in which all physical events take place—an event is a point in spacetime specified by its time and place.
>
> The basic elements of spacetime are events. In any given spacetime, an event is a unique position at a unique time.

Apart from that you will also see ***point in spacetime*** and ***location in spacetime*** used.

Comment: +1: This is very interesting but unfortunately "point in spacetime" isn't a better term than "time and place of ..." for a dumb thing like a meeting.

Comment: Yep sometimes answers can be both correct and unhelpful - sorry about that. Maybe somebody knows a completely different term though. I'm now thinking ***appointment*** and ***date*** often include a meeting place as well as a meeting time.

Answer (score 1):

The [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rendezvous) defines *rendezvous* as:

> an arrangement to meet someone, especially secretly, at a particular place and time, or the place itself:

It's not *precisely* what you're asking for, but it might work depending on the exact context you need.

Other options that might work include [setting](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/setting):

> the time and the place in which the action of a book, film, play, etc. happens

or [appointment](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/appointment):

> a formal arrangement to meet or visit someone at a particular time and place

Answer (score 0):

'Time&place'? Is that any good?